# Select word from value

Tags: jquery

I have input

```
<input type="hidden" value="Select Value 11121 DataValue " name="111" id="222"/>
```

I select value with jQuery

```
alert( $('#222').val() );
```

but

how can I choose only "11121" from this input value with jQuery ?

I can create a filter  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a javascript regex to get the numeric value out of that string:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/\d{5}/igm);

var myNumericValue = regex.exec($('#222').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it make more sense to create four inputs that are hidden, each one with one of the values from the one

in your post?  I would do that rather than try to parse out certain strings from a single  input value.  Just give each a unique id and go from there.

If you really want to keep one, you could do the following:

```
<input type="hidden" value="Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4" id="some_id" name="some_name" />
```

and pluck out the values with:

```
var vals = $('#some_id').val().split(/\W+/);
```

and then access them by position:

```
var val1 = vals[0]; // "Value1"
var val2 = vals[1]; // "Value2"
...
```

Comment: i this case I need select only by value , a cant compare bu Id, Id will be change

Comment: I know, a have same value 

ade8c3ac-55c1-dd11-bc33-001e0b8014eb

and a cand get All value,